# Jacoco Unit testing for multi flavored android app

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to generate a Jacoco for Unit tests, and tried this solution

https://medium.com/swlh/multi-module-multi-flavored-test-coverage-with-jacoco-in-android-bc4fb4d135a3

This is not the Kotlin app.

Unfortunately, the unit tests are running fine, but the reports are not generated.

I have around 2 build types (Debug, and Release) and 5 flavors in my project, can someone guide me on getting the jacoco reports in xml and html?

Thanks

This works fine.
https://medium.com/swlh/multi-module-multi-flavored-test-coverage-with-jacoco-in-android-bc4fb4d135a3

But reports are not being generated.